# BRAVO value won't be found after a SQL SELECT CONTAINS

Tags: sql-server, contains

I have a very strange behavior on sql server.

I have a User table with one row having BRAVO as last name.

When I use this simple request:

```
select * from User u where contains (u.LastName, 'BRAVO')
```

it finds no result.
If I update User table and set the lastname BRAVO to CRAVO (or any other letter) and call

```
select * from User u where contains (u.LastName, 'CRAVO')
```

it will work.

Is BRAVO a reserved word in SQL server? Am I missing something?

Thx

Comment: See if it comes up in the default stoplist `SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_system_stopwords WHERE language_id = 1033;`

Comment: OMG, that was it, many thx!

Comment: [Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15): "Full-text queries perform *linguistic searches* against text data in full-text indexes by operating on words and phrases based on the rules of a particular language..." - I'd strongly suggest not trying to use them for non-linguistic content.

Answer (score 0):

By default when you create a full text index it is associated with a system stoplist.Default stoplist has more than 150 words for english language.You can run below query and see all the stop words for english language for a particular database.

```
 SELECT stopword,language_id FROM sys.fulltext_system_stopwords WHERE language_id = 1033
```

**What is a stop list ? :**

Stopwords are managed in databases by using objects called stoplists. A stoplist is a list of stopwords that, when associated with a full-text index, is applied to full-text queries on that index.

**What is a stop word ? :**

To prevent a full-text index from becoming bloated, SQL Server has a mechanism that discards commonly occurring strings that do not help the search. These discarded strings are called stopwords. During index creation, the Full-Text Engine omits stopwords from the full-text index.

You can use the below query to find the system specified stop words in English Language :

```
SELECT ssw.stopword, slg.name
      FROM sys.fulltext_system_stopwords ssw
      JOIN sys.fulltext_languages slg
      ON slg.lcid = ssw.language_id
      WHERE slg.lcid =1033
```

So, if you include these words in full text search, **including BRAVO** (for exact match, match giving in double quotes) it won’t give you the exact result.